# Как делать отладку JS, который подгружается динамически?

Tags: javascript, yii2, отладка

В *Yii2* есть ассеты (с css и js), их можно подключить в отдельных представлениях. Бывают ситуации, когда представление подгружается через ajax. а вместе с ним и ассеты со скриптами. В итоге в браузере в панели разработчика на вкладке Sources их просто нет и возможности поставить breakpoint нет.

Как в таком случае отладить скрипты? Поставить бряк и пройтись по методам?

Есть вариант писать слово `debugger;` каждый раз. Но не сильно хочется.

---

UPD:  Кажется судя по Network в браузере - Yii подтягивает ajax'ом подтягивает скрипты из папок -

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 2):

Я не знаком с Yii2 и не знаю как там устроены ассеты, но в теории есть только два способа динамически создать js - *eval* и *new Function*. Думаю Yii2 использует один их них. Для обеих способов можно указать параметр *sourceURL* с помощью которого браузер сможет отображать код и запоминать брекпоинты даже после перезагрузки страницы.

Вот пример кода с new Function

```
var foo = new Function(`console.log("called foo"); 
                       //# sourceURL=my-foo1.js`);
document.body.addEventListener("click", foo);
```

И вот пример кода с eval

```
var script = `function foo() {
               console.log('called foo');
             }
             //# sourceURL=my-foo2.js`;
eval(script);
document.body.addEventListener("click", foo, false);
```

После выполнения такого кода в дереве с доменами добавится группа (no domain) в которой будут функции доступны для отладки.
Вот видео как это все выглядит:
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1f7m0drdLfi8KyCJtOGwr2dGB1MScG5Zn/view
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1vEVT-lN4HDcwHkIOYJykWBY6xDPtMUEj/view

ps: также посмотрите в сторону Workspaces и Local Overrides, они очень удобные и возможно помогут в вашем вопросе.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ. Кажется судя по Network в браузере - Yii не делает ни то ни другое. Он просто ajax'ом подтягивает скрипты из папок - https://i.stack.imgur.com/K3MzT.png

Comment: Просто скачать js файл не достаточно. Что происходит со скриптом после скачивания? Может он просто добавляется в DOM?

Comment: Да. как раз в DOM того контента, которое было подгружено ajax'ом

Comment: Сейчас получается найти данные только консоли в event listener https://i.stack.imgur.com/Hpgq7.png

Comment: Давайте минимальный воспроизводимый пример, а то такой диалог затянется надолго.